# How to make a flexible "garden" hose that can be controlled from both ends without losing shape?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation

I've been spinning my brain for the last few days trying to figure out how to do this. Basically, I need to make a hose (single tube shape, it doesn't have to be twisted like the image) that:

(1) Is naturally affected by gravity.
[image]

(2) Can be controlled from both ends of the hose, so both end points can be manipulated in keyframes.
[image]

(3) Won't deform or lose it's hose-like appearance when being moved around (like if someone was to literally move a garden house around in their front lawn).

Can anyone offer some insight into how I could accomplish this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out this tutorial? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQs9f4x0gw May be helpful.

Comment: @PaulGonet, thanks for the reply. That video was very helpful, and it did give me some ideas to possibly make something work.

However, if there was a way to make that be affected by gravity, then we'd be in business.

Comment: Unlike the phone cord, your hose won't need to stretch, so you could use the bezier curve used for stretching the phone cord to simulate the effects of gravity, instead.

Comment: This may be a solution for you: [Rig that reacts to gravity](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity)

Comment: Thanks to you both! Between these two solutions, I believe I have a way to make this happen!