# How to connect and control a ragdoll?

Tags: physics, bones, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I want to evolve walking creatures like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5xC80q69t4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFJkpVWTQVM

But have been struggling to set up physics of joints of a ragdoll. This is the best I got so far

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeWCDx7V60c (project link in the description of the video)

But you can see cubes are not really following bones and they even fall apart at some point. I connected those cubes through Rigid Body Joint constraints and made them follow bone orientation (`cube.worldOrientation = bone.worldOrientation`) through python which in turn must be controlled by neural network output but for now they are just controlled by some sinusoidal functions of time. There must definitely better way to do this or at least improve on this.

Comment: Related links: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HryXEpIz-cg), [2](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity)

Comment: @Mentalist, I've seen 1 and it didn't help. 2 looks like it's made for artistic purposes, I however need it to maintain collision physics and be able to crudely simulate some robot which will evolve behaviors based on that.