# How to apply physics to a part of my mesh

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

Let me start by saying I am not at all fluent with Blender.

I just modeled a character with long ears. I am now taking my first steps in rigging and animating it. The rig worked quite well and a basic animation works as well.

Now the problem. These long ears of my character move along with the head very statically. It looks very unnatural. I guess I could add a bunch of bones in it and move them into position one by one but that sounds counter productive. So I tried adding softbody physics to just the ears. I basically enabled softbody and assigned a vertex group with the ears to the mass property, but now the ears just bounce up and down.

Can anyone please advice on how I can make the ears naturally follow the animation of the rest of the body, and the head in particular?

Thanks!

Comment: Would something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41357/7806) work? You can always mess with the settings of the simulation to make the ears more stiff, or more floppy if you so please.

Comment: Looks useful indeed. In my case the "hat" is actually part of the full mesh, but if I link the ear bones to the empties following the cloth, it may actually work. Ill need some time to try this, and will report back when I did.