# How to rig a hips bag

Tags: rigging

[image]

I'd like to rig a hips bag that flaps when the character runs/jumps. How can I do that? I have been working on it in quite a while now. It would be greatly appreciated if you guys can help.

Comment: try to see if this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity can be adapted to your case...

Comment: Wow that was quick ^-^ thank you m.ardito, I'll try and let you know if it works :)