# Apply rigid body physics to mesh with armature?

Tags: armature, rigid-body-simulation

Is it possible to easily apply a rigid body to ( Parts of/ a complete ) mesh with a armature in a way so that it reacts to gravity?

Comment: yes, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity

Comment: Would it work the same for a rigid body? Seems it describes how to apply a cloth sim, to a armature not a rigid body.

Comment: The second answer is a solution using rigid bodies