# How do I keep cloth attached to a rig while still falling with gravity?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

So I made this character yesterday, and today I added a scarf and a rig and such. I assumed the cloth would follow the mesh with the rig, which it kinda does, but now when it falls if I lean the character over it's not following gravity.... any thoughts? Thanks!!! [image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity

Comment: you need to pin part of your scar and animate it with an armature. You don't sim the entire scarf, it'd be practically impossible. The real proper mind set is to: 1. make a proxy scarf - something low poly and has roughly the same shape of your scarf; 2. rig your entire scarf; 3. pin your rig to the topos of your proxy scarf. If you do it properly you'll get some very convincing results.