# How do I make an automatic tail that is bone rigged?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I have character that has a bone rigged tail but how do I set up the bones to automatically behave like a real tail automatically.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Not 100% the same but i've been a huge fan of this tail tutorial. Perhaps it suits your needs! http://blenderlounge.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1251

Comment: I'll try in the meanwhile and see it it suits my needs.

Comment: Try the Jiggle Armature addon... I love it for stuff like this : https://github.com/cheece/JiggleArmature

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity

Comment: The suggestions were very helpful thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated]

Simplest tail rig ever possible.

The tail has 8 bones the last bone is its tip.

In pose mode.

Adjust all influence to about .5

Add a bone constraint to the 6th bone "track to" the 8th bone. 

Add a bone constraint to the 4th bone "track to" the 6th bone. 

Add a bone constraint to the 2d bone "track to" the 4th bone.

Done.