# Rigging a hose to follow a robot arm

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm doing an industrial robot and I want a hose from the base up to the robot arm and I want the hose to follow the robot arm movement in a natural way. Is this possible and what approach is the best? Do I need to rigg the hose with several bones 
 and then animate the hoses bones for every key frame or is there a way that the hose just follow the robot arm in an automatic way?

Comment: This question shares the same general principle: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity

Comment: Google is your friend http://www.rab3d.com/tut_blen_2-63_hooks.php

Comment: The only thing unsatisfactory about the Rab3D method is that the hose is allowed to stretch, and it's not using physics, so you would need to keyframe it manually. In some cases this will be fine. But I personally prefer a rig that uses physics and responds to the motion of the mechanical arm.

Comment: I'd opt for a softbody simulation on a string of edges, hooked at each end. You can then add a Skin modifier with Subsurface modifier to fill it out to a hose.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This tutorial and it's approach worked fine for my project. My question is solved! Thanks!