# The armature stays in the air instead of falling

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation

If I click on Alt+A the armature (rigged) doesn't fall, it just stays in the air. I tried to add a "rigid body" but this doesn't help.

(sorry about my english-speaking)

Comment: afaik, you can't enable an "armature" (as blender object) as a rigid body... you can just use rigid body constraints on it...  see this maybe related  answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/rig-that-reacts-to-gravity