# Animation: How to bake physics to export to Sketchfab

Tags: animation

Following this tutorial

[How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct)

I made this animation

[image]

I am having trouble to bake it/export it so I can display the animated chains in Sketchfab or so. I tried exporting the mesh as alembic and then baking the action to keyframes but that did not seem work.

Here is the file (Blender 2.8):
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the toruses and the rig then export it to fbx. In the fbx exporter "Main" tab (lower left corner) check in "Selected objects". In the "Animation" tab disable "All actions" and "NLA Strips".

Comment: That works. Thank you! So if I leave "All actions" and "NLA Strips" checked they override the armature animation or why is that?

Comment: If you disable this options you will export what you see. The aramture movement made by two components: 1. A LocRotScale information, what you save in the actions with keyframes 2. The Constraints which also affects the bones. If you leave checked these options you will export only the LocRotScale values, the constraints won't do anything.