# Rig behaving strange after parenting it to an object

Tags: physics

Following this tutorial: [How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct)

I get the physics effect that I am looking for as long as I animate the underlying cloth.
[image]

If I parent the cloth and the armature to an object and animate the object (like the tutorial suggests) instead I get some strange behaviour. Flickering, weird movement, stopping in a strange position ...

[image]

Here is the blendfile without the parenting (Blender 2.8).

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51625

Comment: I'm not sure you even need an armature for it... possibly just for only the 1st link?

Comment: Looks like a dependency cycle to me. The parent is most likely colliding with some driver, constraint or other parent .