# How to add collision for a Physics enabled tail?

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a character with a rather large tail and thanks to this answer-> [How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct)

I was able to give it physics to give me some really cool tail movement during the character walking, running, etc. But I noticed it clips through everything. I tried adding collision to the tail mesh but nothing, and the "Cloth mesh" for the tail doesn't collide with anything either.

Is there a way to add collision to this sort of physics enabled rig?

Comment: I'm not sure how about this exact approach but generally you need to add collision to other objects which tails could collide with.

Comment: Tried that as well and didn't work.