# Gravity Rig : how to combine it with a rigged cloth and character?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, parent

I have a rigged character with cloth on it. As the cloth sim was not convincing for the coat (high ressources consumption, kind of shaky, anyway), I tried to create a rig reacting to gravity thanks to this post : [How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct)

Everything is good, except for the parenting part. How can I use this "gravity rig" to guide my long coat behavior ? Considering I also need it to follow my pre-rigged character.

[image]

I'm sorry I can't upload the blend file, but here is a little gif showing you the "gravity rig", then the pre-rigged character, then the long coat : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk0vK.gif

It is probably obvious, but I'm a beginner, only using Blender since the first lockdown, so I have difficulties to figure it out on my own.

As a side note, this could be, in my opinion, a good way to rig hairs made from curves ! (I'll definitely try it on my character), and it seems to be waaaayy less demanding in terms of calculation power, am I wrong ?

As usual, thanks for the help. This thread is a life-saver haha.
See ya !

Comment: `As the cloth sim was not convincing for the coat (high ressources consumption, kind of shaky, anyway)`
you have to use a low resolution collision object, and a low resolution cloth. Then add a surface deform on your high cloth object that is controlled by the low rez cloth. Also bake because that is faster

Comment: your method seems very tedious; why not using a mesh deform modifier for example? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA