# How to make Dynamic Bone for Unity

Tags: animation

I got a little robot I’m making for a game in Unity. I’m not too good at using physics in Blender, I understand this is probably something super simple, but how would I go about making his antenna bob back and forth while still staying attached to his head? This is what his antenna looks like, unfinished.

[image: Robot]

I kinda just want it to wave back and forth as he walks, not a baked animation, I want it to move dynamically. Would I use a soft body for the antenna? But then how do I bake the physics for Unity?

Sorry for the noob question, I'm evidently terrible at rigging...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't export physics. Try to rig the antenna and fake the motion with curve modifiers in the Graph Editor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob at rigging, how exactly do you achieve this?

Comment: Try a clothsim rig https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct