# Apply cloth physics to only one part of character

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I have a character whose belly I'm trying to make bounce as he walks.

I can't apply a weight paint to the entire character as it's way too CPU intensive, so to achieve this I make a copy of the character and cut the geometry of his belly into a separate mesh (grid filling in the cut faces so I can inflate and bounce the belly with cloth pressure physics).

This all works well, but ounce I have his belly bouncing I need to get this separated mesh back onto the character.

I can't figure out a good way to do this, because the separated belly mesh needs to now somehow reattach to the character and blend in without things looking very odd. What's an effective way to achieve this?

Comment: "I can't apply a weight paint to the entire character": what do you mean exactly? maybe your mesh is too high in topology, in that case you need to reduce the amount of faces

Comment: Yep it's a Daz character which has a high number of faces, that's why I'm attempting the trick of just having one part of the body use physics

Comment: I'm not sure using a vertex group to exclude a part of your object from cloth simulation will be the main problem, high-topology is the main problem imho

Comment: Use Mesh Deform modifier to transfer bouncing mesh onto original model.  It would be probably more consistent to have lowpoly character, do sim physics on this and transfer by modifier (not just a belly itself).

Comment: Thanks both. For the latter suggestion, do you mean copy the entire model, reduce the polys, apply the physics and place a a Mesh Deform to attach it to the original high poly character?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct

Comment: If you can to lowpoly by un-subdiv ... Yes ... Just Duarte's link to Mentalist's answer is better way to go ... You simulate only two edges translated to a belly bone.  There is also jiggle bone addon, but there was some glitches on playback if I remember right.