# How to combine rigid body with cloth physics?

Tags: rigging, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I made a bunny head mesh and i followed [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct) to make the ears behave as I intended.

Now I need a way to avoid the clipping between the ears and the head. I think I might be able to achieve it by adding a copy of the head (without the ears) inside the head itself and then adding the corresponding simulations, but I haven't tried it yet.

[image]

Here's the clipping I'm talking about.

Comment: Physics Properties > Collisions > enable Self Collisions ...? Edit ... Ears are not part of sim, Ears are driven by Rig driven by cloth sim object, right? So probably just enable Collision physics for the head?

Comment: @vklidu i cant find the self collisions option. Im on blender 2.92.0 if that helps

Comment: @vklidu i tried that (enabling collisions for the head) but it didnt worked, it still clips trough(?) it

Comment: Right ... I got it ... you have to extrude cloth sim object to have a face (edge is not colliding) and also head can't be a Collider because cloth is inside collider :) You have to add another object as collider hidden from rendering. Answer on the way with example ...

Comment: @vklidu yep, i ended up figuring that out by myself, but thanks anyways

Comment: Great you solved it by your self. Anyway since site is meant to be a knowledge base I post the answer ... maybe helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- An object with Cloth sim has to be extruded from edges into faces to be taken into collision account (edges are not colliding)

[image]

- For collision you have to add another object of head size (dummy), parent to a Head object and in Outliner disable from Rendering

[image]

[image]

Note: Original suggestion to use Head as Collider is nonsense, because cloth sim is inside of the Head (I expected vertex group to exclude ears from sim ...).