# How do I attach an animated rigid body to a cloth sim?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to add cloth simulated straps to this helmet, one of the straps has a buckle on the bottom. I've set the buckle to be a rigid body and parented it to an empty - which is parented to 3 vertices of the bottom of the strap. The straps are pinned to the helmet.

[image: Swinging Straps]

I'm unable to "stiffen" the part where the buckle attaches, so when the mesh of the cloth simulated strap scales during animation, it scales the buckle as well. (I've tried playing with the weight paints but it either just holds the strap down where the buckle is or does nothing)

[image: Close up of distorted buckle]

Comment: hello, not sure how could the buckle could scale... maybe share your helmet + buckle? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just for clarification: is there a need for the buckle to be a rigid body, since it's parented to the empty I would guess it only has to be a collision object for the cloth sim? Or am I missing here something?

Comment: Probably better to use this tech https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct ... or sometimes unstable Wiggle or Sping Bones addon.