# How to make whiskers interact with the ground?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, physics, rigify

I'm trying to make Cometo's whiskers interact with the ground. I couldn't find any good videos on what I'm trying to do, so I came here. Cometo has long whiskers that I want them to drag on the ground every time she moves. Is there any way I can achieve this?

[image]
The green circles in the front are the whiskers

Comment: Maybe with cloth or physics simulation, but that would make animation more HW required... is it impossible to do with IK?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with IK.

Comment: Maybe so https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41235/107598? It's a very simple cloth simulation that controls the mesh via IK controls. I'm not sure if that works for your whiskers but might be worth a try.