# What's the general way of making clothes that can be used for animation?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I feel a bit confused about clothing.
I'm making a new character and I want to make him some clothes.
To give you an idea, it's gonna look like a cleric robe, so there will be several layers of clothing on top of each other and it needs to be loose, generally speaking.

I'm currently sewing it using the cloth sim so that I can have nice details.
But it requires quite a lot of geometry, with ever-increasing baking times, so I doubt that's the right way to animate a cloth. If I make a single animation and the baking time already takes 20mn just to calculate 120 frames, for a single piece of cloth,  well, I guess that's not the way to do it.

My questions are: how do I keep as many details as possible while lowering the geometry to the minimum? What's the general workflow?

Comment: Animation with a cloth simulation is a very challenging task. I would retopologize the sewn cloth and bake the details (small wrinkles, etc) to a normal image texture. If the sewing takes too long because of the many layers you can create a low-poly dummy for the next layer (apply the cloth modifier and decimate). For animation, I would only simulate the loose parts (sleeves, cloak) and pin the parts that fit tightly to the body with the *Pin Group* setting. Alternatively, the loose parts can be rigged with extra bones (no simulation in the animation)

Comment: Or try a combination of a rig and a very simple cloth sim to animate the loose parts: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41235/107598 - (not sure if this works for robe sleeves, robes and cloaks)