# How to simulate bendy antennas/sensors?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I want to simulate the antenna of an insect following the movement of its head, what would be the best way?

I tried simulating using cloth and soft body sims, but its either folding too much or very jiggly. I also thought about bendy bones but then again I would have to place keyframes, which I want to avoid.

This is the result I got with playing around with the cloth sim and a weight map but Im not really satisfied because faster movements will tear it apart.
[image]

So is there a way which is ideal for that kind of simulation? Thanks in advance!

[image]
This is the file if anyone is interested in the settings beeing used.

Comment: There is a free add-on called Wiggle Bones that maybe can help you. Just throwing the tip in here until someone comes whit a proper answer.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Wiggle Bones would be a good idea, but a Cloth simulation should work fine, it's just a matter of settings

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41357/35559) help, at all? .. maybe you've already been there.

Comment: The wiggle bones add on looks very promising, thank you guys! The cloth sim could work too I guess but nailing the settings can be difficult and I havent even tried it on a more detailed model, this one was just for testing. Also I added the file if someone is interested in the settings.