Physical Hair Rig (Cloth Sim + Armature): mesh follows later than the bone
I watched this course on YouTube and followed it. It worked well in the course, but it didn't work well because I did it.
I thought the constraints were a problem, so I turned them off. I turned off the simulation, and I turned off the parent relationship.
However, the issue is not fixed. So after applying weights to DEF, I looked to see if the weights went in somewhere else and there was nothing like that either.



What course on YT did you follow and how is that supposed to work?

Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41235/107598

https://youtu.be/BKtVuqnCbK0?si=cJp0RLWe6fLWaXif
I follow this youtube. youtuber just auto weight. it work well. Thank you for relate question.

You forgot about the ponytail_phyObj helper object and used the visible ponytail. This way you have created a cyclic dependency. The rig shown in the video is very similar to the linked question. It just uses vertex groups instead of Empty objects. But you need that ponytail_phyObj mesh for the cloth simulation. The bones will then follow it and deform the visible ponytail (hair tail object)

Thank you for your response. I solved it using Wiggle Born 2 add-on. That's much more comfortable..
